# Getting an error when installing tensorflow

Tags: python, powershell, tensorflow, pip

I am getting an error when trying to download tensorflow through pip.

```
PS C:\Users\12158> pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: 
none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Very strange. Through research there seems to be an issue with newer python versions and installing tensorflow. Is there an option to not have to downgrade python?

```
PS C:\Users\12158> python -c "import struct; print(8 *struct.calcsize('P'))"

64
PS C:\Users\12158>
```

My version is Python 3.12.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of python --version, make sure you are not using the 32-bit version of python.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow is now only available up to version 3.11 of Python.

You may use Python 3.11 and try again.

Please refer to [the installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) for more information.